# waypoint navigation in warehouse conditions

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My question is about using waypoint for an AMR.
Does follow_waypoint works really well in warehouse conditions ? is it the best solution if i want to develop a complete navigation solution for warehouse ?

any other solutions/remarks ... are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379542/waypoint-navigation-in-warehouse-conditions/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course its not the best solution for any given specific application, its a generic demo I built in an afternoon :-) But its a reasonable starting point for a proof of concept or a component of your larger autonomy system. I for one use it frequently at home for various testing and see no reason why it couldn't work in a warehouse environment. In fact, my current project is making some POCs of waypoint following in a warehouse for a pseudo-inspection task that I'm using the ROS2 waypoint follower server for without much issue.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-06-03**:
Yes I misexpressed myself while asking the question when i said "the best solution ...".
Thanks a lot for the answer.